# How to get Spring bean by name

Tags: java, spring

How can I get the bean by passing  only the class name using `BeanFactoryUtils`

I'm trying below, but this is not working

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils;
baseDao= BeanFactoryUtils.originalBeanName("RegionDaoImpl");
```

**RegionDao**

```
@Component
public class RegionDaoImpl implements BaseDao<Region> {
...
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The bean name is `regionDaoImpl` **not** `RegionDaoImpl`. ALso getting by name is generally nog a smart thing to do, or doing a lookup in the first place is a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`ListableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html), then you call [`beanOfType()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryUtils.html#beanOfType-org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory-java.lang.Class-), e.g.:

```java
RegionDaoImpl dao = BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfType(beanFactory, RegionDaoImpl.class);
```

Generally, the `ListableBeanFactory` will be an [`ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html), so you need the application context of your Spring application. How to get that depends on your application type, and where the code calling `beanOfType()` is located.

It is usually better to let Spring auto-wire the object into your class, which does the same thing, i.e. lookup the bean by type.

```java
@Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowire
    private RegionDaoImpl regionDao;

    ...
}
```

If you want to lookup by name, you'd call [`beanFactory.getBean()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-), but that seems kind of redundant:

```java
RegionDaoImpl dao = beanFactory.getBean("RegionDaoImpl", RegionDaoImpl.class);
```

Comment: He wants to get by `name` not by `type, which might even fail in this case due to an interface based proxy (probably). However doing a lookup is bad regardless of how one does the lookup (unless one is writing a framework/library) so +1 for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum The question doesn't show what the declared type of `baseDao` is, but you can't really use it much unless it's `RegionDaoImpl`. I mean, it could be `BaseDao<Region>`, but then you wouldn't have access to any Region-specific extra methods, and if it is `RegionDaoImpl`, then it's better to use `beanOfType()`, since that it type-safe, and prevents typo's.

Comment: Which wouldn't work with an interface proxy, as that type isn't present that way.